# How does one run a program at startup that requires UAC elevation?

Tags: admin, startup, uac, elevation

I have a program that monitors malicious files and deletes them. However it needs administrator rights to run. This program runs at startup, however the UAC popup is annoying for end users, especially if it appears every time the user logs in. Anyway, I am wondering if there is a way to run the program with administrator rights at startup with out nagging the user with the UAC popup.

P.S: Disabling UAC is not a good idea because of security issues for the users.

Comment: You cannot bypass the UAC prompt. The usual answer is to run your application as a service.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Windows Vista (thankfully) blocked applications on startup that tried to elevate. Windows 7 removed the block; causing applications to try to do it.

Your best choice is to:

- add a Scheduled Task to run your application *"At system startup"*, and have it run *"With highest privileges available"*

[image]

Comment: where can i download this tool ?

Comment: @TanishqBanyal It's built into Windows: **Task Scheduler**

Comment: i meant that "malicious software installation tool"

Comment: @TanishqBanyal You have to write that malicous program yourself.

Comment: I know but i was asking about that screenshot you posted. Why does the title say "malicious software Installation Tool" ?

Comment: @TanishqBanyal That was the name i gave to the scheduled task.